# find_or_create_by trying to create duplicate records with hmt association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm curious if there is another way of achieving the following.

Setup:

```
class Cabin < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :feature_groupings
  has_many :features, through: :feature_groupings
end

class Feature < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :feature_groupings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cabins, through: :feature_groupings

  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end

class FeatureGrouping < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :feature
  belongs_to :cabin
end

c1 = Cabin.create(name: "Standard")
c2 = Cabin.create(name: "Luxury")
c1.features.create(name: "Wifi")
f = c2.features.find_or_create_by(name: "Wifi")
```

This results in

```
2.4.0 :006 > f.errors.full_messages
 => ["Name has already been taken"]
```

Is there a cleaner way of associating feature (id: 1, name: "Wifi") with c2 (id: 2, name: "Luxury") than simply:

```
c2.features << Feature.find_or_create_by(name: "Wifi")
```

I had expected there to be some sort of rails magic using the HMT association to `find_or_create` the feature.

Rails version: 5.0.1

Ruby version: 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that, in doing this:

```
f = c2.features.find_or_create_by(name: "Wifi")
```

you are trying to find or create a feature within the features associated with c2. That's why it's failing, so no, I  don't think there is a (much) nicer way of doing this, as you want to add an existing feature.